# trace_printf not working with floats

Tags: c, eclipse, floating-point, microcontroller, stm32

Using Eclipse IDE to program an STM32F0xx Discovery board.  Attempting to do some math buy taking the TIM2 clock counter and dividing it by 48000000 to arrive at a time period.

If I declare my working variable as uint32_t it gives me the truncated answer.  What I want is a decimal value and I would have thought that declaring it as a float would solve the issue, but when I do that nothing gets printed.

```
variable = (TIM2->CNT)/48000000;
trace_printf("%i",variable);
```

works with a uint32_t declared variable however changing the place holder to %f or even leaving as is for a float declaration produces nada.  Does it need to be cast as a float?

Its been so long since I've done any C coding and I'm certain I've had this same issue before when using CooCox but I can't remember what the solution was back then.

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~brent/ceng355/printf.html

Comment: @harmic - You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TY @harmic!  [http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~brent/ceng355/printf.html](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/%7Ebrent/ceng355/printf.html)

> Printing Floating Point Numbers Using trace_printf
>
> To enable the trace_printf to print floating point numbers do the following in your project.
>
> - Under the projects menu item select properties option.
> - Expand out the C/C++ Build Section and select the settings option.
> - Now select the tab "Tool Settings". Under the section "Cross ARM C++ Linker" select Miscellaneous.
> - Click the checkbox that says "Use float with nano printf (-u_printf_float).
> - Now click apply and then OK.
> - Rebuild your project and floating point numbers should now print.
>
> Please see picture below for configuration settings and sample code with results.

[image]

That's exactly what I needed.  I'll spread the word around in class about that link.